# Add toolbar to dynamically generated BIRT report

Tags: birt, birt-deapi

I am using `IReportEngine` to open a template report and `IReportRunnable` to created the elements of the report. Then `IRunAndRenderTask` to display the report and return it as HTML. what I don't know is how  to add the Birt toolbar  and the navigation bar to the generated report.  Any idea or suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both toolbar and pagination are components of the webviewer, not components of the BIRT engine API. If reports are generated with the report engine API, as far a i know there is no way to display these elements out-of-the-box: you need to implement your own toolbar and pagination widget.

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks a lot